# test sign up with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Devise 1.2 ruby on rails

I'm having difficulty testing sign up. When the user clicks sign up, they're logged in and i should see a flash message. This works but my test fails. Not sure why. How does sign up work? is there some sort of internal redirect that happens? This step fails:
`Then I should see "You have registered successfully. If enabled, a confirmation was sent your e-mail."`

Confirmation is not enabled in my user model.

Comment: this is the test output:     (::) failed steps (::)

expected the following element's content to include "You have registered successfully. If enabled, a confirmation was sent your e-mail.":
You are being redirected.(RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:145:in `/^(?:|I )should see "([^"]*)"$/'
features/registration.feature:38:in `Then I should see "You have registered successfully. If enabled, a confirmation was sent your e-mail."'  I think the YOU ARE BEING REDIRECTED part is the issue, any ideas???

Answer (score 5):

Tehcnically, you shouldn't feel the need to unit test the devise mechanism--the gem itself is well-tested.  I can understand wanting to make sure it is behaving the way you configured it though, so:

Devise definitely redirects after a successful authentication.  It will set the flash message and then redirect either to what you set as the root in your routes file, or if you attempted to access a page within the site and got redirected to the login page, it will redirect you back to the page you were trying to access.

For your test, try testing that you get redirected to what you set as root in your routes.rb fil.  I.e. in the devise instructions, it says to set it like

`root :to => "home#index"`

So, in your test try something like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

    describe YourController do
      include Devise::TestHelpers

      before (:each) do
        @user = Factory.create(:user)
        sign_in @user
      end

      describe "GET 'index'" do
        it "should be successful" do
          get 'index' 
          response.should be_success
        end
        it "should redirect to root" do
          get 'index'
          response.should redirect_to(root_url)
      end
    end
```

You can add your flash message test to this as well.  Hope this helps!